# What is a baseline compiler?

Tags: architecture, compilation, computer-science

I have struggled to find the definition of **baseline compiler** and **baseline interpreter** and I am quite surprised that it’s not mentioned anywhere.

If I am not wrong, a baseline compiler will compile code into a bytecode rather than architecture dependent machine code, right?

Comment: It's not a general concept, it's a [specific thing](https://blog.mozilla.org/javascript/2013/04/05/the-baseline-compiler-has-landed/) that I believe Chrome has copied since it came out.

Comment: @TylerH Oh. That seems really off. Thanks for the comment. Appreciate it.

Comment: @TylerH However, Baseline is the term for their new baseline compiler. Still, what baseline compiler means is a mystery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After digging into many articles and books, I was able to deduce the meaning of “baseline compiler”.

Basically, the job of a **baseline compiler** is to generate bytecode or machine code as fast as possible. This output code (machine code or intermediate code) however is not very optimized for a processor, hence it's very inefficient and slow in runtime.

On the other hand, an **optimization compiler** produces an efficient code but it takes a much longer time to do so.

Hence **baseline compiler** is useful when you want to load and run your application as quickly as possible and later optimize the code with an **optimization compiler** in the background.

Comment: I'm curious about what will happen to bounty if you accept your answer?

Comment: @BladeMight Now you know ;)

Answer (score 6):

I find some information about the topic in the context of JavaScript runtime engines, specifically for web browsers: In short, a baseline compiler is a certain stage during code execution by the runtime engine. It will produce machine code very quickly, but without optimizations for the machine that the code actually runs on. So it is really a method within the broader concept of [just-in-time (JIT) compilation](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/02/a-crash-course-in-just-in-time-jit-compilers/) and therefore conceptually somewhere in between code interpretation and code compilation.

[This article](https://hackernoon.com/webassembly-the-journey-jit-compilers-dfa4081a6ffb) gives some background on JavaScript JIT compilation:

> In summary, after JavaScript code is loaded, the source code is
> transformed into a tree representation called Abstract Syntax Tree or
> AST. After, depending on the engine/operational system/platform,
> either a baseline version of this code is compiled, or a bytecode is
> created to be interpreted. [...]
>
> When a piece of code is executed multiple times, [...],
> the interpreter loses his performance since it needs to
> interpret the same piece of code over and over again, when this
> happens, the profiler marks this piece of code as warm and baseline
> compiler comes to action.
>
> When this code section is executed [...],
> the JIT only needs to take this compiled piece again. When a
> warm code is called several times in the same manner (like same
> types), it’s marked as hot. [...]
>
> When a piece of code is marked as hot, the optimizer compiler
> generates an even faster version of this code.

[Here is another source](https://liveoverflow.com/just-in-time-compiler-in-javascriptcore-browser-0x03/) explaining the concept of about "hot" code and the different tiers of code execution.

[This (older) announcement](https://blog.mozilla.org/javascript/2013/04/05/the-baseline-compiler-has-landed/) talks about Mozilla's (then) new JavaScript engine and the problems that are solved by the included baseline compiler.

[This other Mozilla blog article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2019/08/the-baseline-interpreter-a-faster-js-interpreter-in-firefox-70/) gives very detailed information about code execution, changing the concept even more due to new requirements and conditions:

> However, the modern web has such large codebases that even the
> relatively fast Baseline JIT Compiler spent a lot of time compiling.
> To address this, Firefox 70 adds a new tier called the Baseline
> Interpreter to the pipeline

On the other hand, Chromium seems to have [introduced the concept in 2010](https://blog.chromium.org/2010/12/new-crankshaft-for-v8.html) in its V8 engine (calling it a base compiler), and to have [dropped it again in 2017](https://v8.dev/blog/launching-ignition-and-turbofan).

Answer (score 4):

**To answer your question, you have to understand the inner workings of the Javascript language, through its history and recent developments.**

> JavaScript is defined as an interpreted language but also as compiled on the fly (JIT-Compiled).

The confusion is further compounded by the lack of information in the JavaScript specification itself.

When JavaScript is executed, the JavaScript engine of the browser (V8 on Chrome, SpiderMonkey on Firefox) or the server (V8 with Node.js) must convert the source code into a format understandable by the computer.

**There are two ways to do this: interpreting or compiling the source code.**

> **Interpretation**: The program is translated into machine language during its execution (runtime). Each line is processed on the fly without waiting for a preliminary processing phase.

On the other hand, when a line of code is executed N times (a loop for example), the interpreter must redo the machine language translation N times.

> **Compilation**: Requires a preliminary phase of translation into machine language in order to be able to be executed. All the code is compiled and optimized beforehand by the compiler so that the program can be executed. It is a quid pro quo to alleviate the concern related to the interpreters mentioned above.

Appeared in the mid-90s, JavaScript was little used, we found some instructions in the  tag and calls to functions like onclick or alert.

The interpretation was much simpler and provided perfectly adequate performances for the use cases of the time.

In the 2000s, a race for the performance of web browsers raged to the point that it was called the Browsers war. This is a period during which the main web players (Mozilla, Google) try to optimize their browser to the maximum.

Thus, Firefox unveils SpiderMonkey, the very first JIT compiler which allowed a performance gain of around 20 to 40% compared to the old version of the JavaScript engine.

In the process, Google made available the Chrome browser and its V8 execution engine, including a compilation phase. The latter is often known as “Just in Time” or JIT.

The other browsers (Edge, etc.) have also changed their JavaScript engine by adding a compilation phase. This development improved the speed of JavaScript by 10 times and acted as a lever for its use on previously unthinkable platforms such as server-oriented programming (Node.js).

**“Just in time” and compilation**

> A JIT compiler combines the speed of execution of an interpreter with the optimization provided by a compiler.

JavaScript engines including a JIT are very often composed of 4 essential building blocks:

*A monitor (profiler) who plays the role of conductor
An interpreter, which executes the source code (runtime)
A so-called "basic" compiler that performs some basic optimizations
A compiler called "optimizer" which takes care of making further optimizations if necessary.*

**The (simplified) execution process is as follows:**

1)The monitor calls on the interpreter to execute the code. It analyzes on the fly the function calls made.

2)If the interpreter makes several calls to the same function, the monitor will "tag" it as a warm function.

3)As soon as a function is warm, the monitor communicates with the baseline compiler to indicate that the function is often used and that it must be compiled.

4)The baseline compiler makes some optimizations by generating an optimized version (stub) of each instruction.

5) If a function becomes increasingly warm, it is "tagged" as hot: it must be further optimized.

6)The monitor then decides to send this function to the compiler-optimizer which will produce an even more optimized version than that generated by the baseline compiler.

7)This compiler makes several assumptions about this function, for example, the type of variables. Knowing that JavaScript has dynamic typing, the probability of error is not zero. The compiler can remove its optimization and refer only to the version compiled in step 4: it is a de-optimization operation.

8)The interpreter, who instead of having to re-translate the function into machine language, will directly use its compiled version or its optimized version in order to speed up processing.

*Stage number 7 is subject to performance issues. Indeed, de-optimization can slow down the process in the event that the compiler spends its time optimizing and then de-optimizing the code. This is why some JavaScript engines have an optimization cycle limit.*

Once this threshold is reached, the compiler will stop trying to optimize and refer to the version of the source code in its "raw" form (that of step 1) or to a stub produced in step 4.

Performance level and without going into the details of each JavaScript engine for simplicity, we can see that it rocks: V8 is always in the lead and displays interesting performances.

**Interpreted or Compiled?**

Now that we have a general idea of ​​the execution process, we can risk labeling JavaScript as interpreted or compiled.

JIT compilers translate source code (in machine language) on the fly, and only for performance improvement, this is not an initiative specific to ECMA TC39 or JavaScript.

> JavaScript is therefore an interpreted language, which, as the uses and developments progressed, had to face performance challenges and led to a somewhat “hybrid” mode, mixing interpretation and compilation.

Recently, Mozilla proposed an evolution of its execution engine (HolyJIT) using the Rust language, aimed at improving the performance and security of the compilation process.

At the end of February 2017, the 4 main browsers (Chrome, Safari, Edge and Firefox) announced that the MVP (Miminum Valuable Product) concerning WebAssembly (WASM) was finalized.

It is a pedestal, which associated with JIT compilers, opens the field of possibilities concerning the use of languages ​​other than JavaScript (C ++, Rust) within the browser.

For example, a module developed in a language such as C or Rust can be embedded and used in a JavaScript application without this impacting the browser.

All this is not trivial and requires that the code be compiled via a compiler provided for this purpose so that, as output, a .wasm file is produced.

This is an interesting technology to follow because heavy processing (intensive calculations via CPU or GPU) can very well be developed in an adapted language (C or C ++) and the rest of the application developed in JavaScript.

Here are some interesting articles, they deal with the subject in more depth by focusing on V8:

http://www.jayconrod.com/posts/54/a-tour-of-v8-crankshaft-the-optimizing-compiler

https://v8project.blogspot.fr/2016/08/firing-up-ignition-interpreter.html

http://www.jayconrod.com/posts/51/a-tour-of-v8-full-compiler

https://ponyfoo.com/articles/an-introduction-to-speculative-optimization-in-v8

https://v8project.blogspot.fr/2017/11/csa.html

Answer (score 1):

Sharing my findings

## Regarding Jikes RVM

> The goal of the baseline compiler is to eﬃciently generate code that is ”obviously correct”. It also needs to be easy to port to a new platform and self contained (the entire baseline compiler must be included in all Jikes RVM boot images to support dynamically loading other compilers).

Reference: [Jikes RVM Chapter 13 Compilers](https://www.jikesrvm.org/UserGuide/Compilers/index.html)

> ‘Baseline’ compiler, which exists for debugging and verification purposes; it produces native code that directly implements JVML’s stack model as closely as possible and is in many ways comparable to an interpreter.

Reference: [Quantifying the Benefits of SSA-Based Mobile Code](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272990/1-s2.0-S1571066105X02183/1-s2.0-S1571066105051613/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIE6BCzces1swtsDM%2BXRZ9JjophdMl6V2Ig9FnN3Al26wAiEA2CZLFPlcxalYXpCy35HkRAmvvlMwq7DVy4j9RNgQe7oqvQMIiP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARACGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDN9IOq1aD5IDl1kPRiqRAx9e0FG5xwpky7K3RCmmJLOc6QBvSi2tkYFvsEQM59E50rQAbIqYYmksxukJ5DFb2ykV8ajp7REKfEcGPtdw0gDBeVgLRq5ditMSKTu%2Fb%2BgLkC4qxBLEP8K4KAbdbREs695Bj%2FSseEAimPnGz0bs%2BCWblXeO6lIsQRrCj%2BPFrEV545P0q1WPKD2o6TbAFC5pz8C0aIVBWdK7M9ZuwkQu86%2Ba2JhS1lhZ%2BLgMsieCy1Ln2FEzbllNfgnmQfA1fLG3WNkplQQidnL8tTrhgJTzpktnOhZ5Em4RMv9B3zv9L68m4GjB3HUz7z7se8qA9ItMJdlCw2UQKPqnQ0dPEkI07jT30GF95iDbnDG9GWKLPTqkzYAd4oEJHbH7Z%2BXumtpixBoLCclIlQlCfDqWL4WKgZkg8elR5qM%2BPxxrY1uL61nu1CgzAu3org0IOlyRE4AfWWYv%2BoryeOXl4HNTlQ37pnYQoUGL18TVS4%2F%2Bk4ORRzS%2F1b19cygj1Obx5xnF0BhyE1ephUKAMrv6L6kdDS5AQQRRML6VgPEFOusBKCAiwuMDk3utXT1kEVxRaRj%2B6bGYdcqzo%2BB%2F7eOzundHxYb6%2FQdU8QF8AJoMpEiFw9diCbmUVJQG8rLx%2F9AV59tYKFIHmxV63BYVp4XCUfFEWYht6cumHkY1470RX8DsyGkQat%2F6sXOPfnC5HUUDrN9trEdHi9a5a1NrrzyhvnRPdUqV%2F2dWCXARt49560pMXajlEYXByz%2F%2FIA5Ys6hJoYOKMd1vipLLLMTKdCc6bsbs7ZOXSseriUytz16RBzDGZaVdpUeDsVE9o2pewCAOWrjAAQUpJBdGkJ1fHqVDT0Zy8KZ8JMx3s1PWlw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200116T080205Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY27Q4YS6O%2F20200116%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=6fc8c0c8594cdcf705606272b924d02ef8b67109e04686e8481b0fb155329197&hash=b22feefcf8f5952e44d8b22b55fc3e7c80d16ad228348d34a8549ad08d50aa08&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S1571066105051613&tid=spdf-045568bb-439b-468d-acce-2fb5e62e11dc&sid=62911a0d45a80544dd09e65431ffe28053d8gxrqa&type=client)

---

## Regarding JavaScript

### First explanation

[image: Tiers in JavaScriptCore, the compiler in WebKit.WebKit is the open-source version of Apple’s Safari.]

> When  the code starts to run, it is processed by the Interpreter. In the background, the Baseline compiler generates code containing profile information. This Baseline code is later invoked. As it  executes  and  popular  functions  are  discovered,  they  are recompiled by the more advanced DFG compiler. Finally, for  the  really  hot  functions,  the  most  advanced  compiler (FTL) creates very specialized, high-performance code.

Reference: [NoMap: Speeding-Up JavaScript Using Hardware Transactional Memory](https://iacoma.cs.uiuc.edu/iacoma-papers/hpca19_1.pdf)

### Second explanation

[image]

Reference: [Server-Side Type Profiling for OptimizingClient-Side JavaScript Engines](https://sites.cs.ucsb.edu/~benh/research/papers/kedlaya15server.pdf)

Comment: By the way,  'baseline compiler' has flicked in GNU Autoconf Archive documentation too.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

`BaseLine Compiler` are nothing but a compiler which is used to convert the code into `MachineCode` that is `bytecode` . Their characteristic is that they are not that much optimistic as compared to a `Full JIT Compiler`(Full Just-In-Time compiler) this bytecode generated can be further optimised .

**Example:**
[image: SpiderMonkey]

Their is an example of `FireFox Javascript Engine (SpiderMonkey)`.
In FireFox engine their are two compilers apart from Interpreter  the first one is BaseLine Compiler and the second one is the Compiler which give the most optimised code. So the bytecode is tranfered to BaseLine Compiler and after that those bytecode is transfered to Full Compiler which gives the optimised code.